# What provider to use for IntelliSense information in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I am developing a small VSCode Extension to provide documentation functionalities to a specific language. Now I want to integrate the documented information into the VSCode Tooltip and IntelliSense. I already managed the tooltip part using `registerHoverProvider`.
Now I'm searching for the right one to register a provider for
[IntelliSense Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGrI1.png).

Could anyone help me out or give a hint?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider%3CT%3E

Comment: As I understand registerCompletionItemProvider add the capability to add entries, like methods, properties, etc., to the IntelliSense list. I just want to add descriptions to existing elements.

Comment: I've been playing around a bit with registerCompletionItemProvider, and as far as I can see, it's not possible to hook into existing CompletionItem's and attach information. From the documentation it looks like the method [resolveCompletionItem()](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#CompletionItemProvider.resolveCompletionItems) is the correct starting point, but it is only triggered on my own CompletionItem's.

@LexLi More ideas or am I doing something wrong?